# devise:Add new user by existing user in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

In a rails project, I use `devise` to manage my user. Now I want remove `sign up` from `login-page` and just user that allready exist, can register new user.

What the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the sign up link from the login page, install the Devise Views and remove that link from the "shared/links" partial.

In your terminal, generate the Devise views:

```
$ cd path/to/app
$ rails generate devise:views users
```

In the folder views/devise that is created, edit the document shared/_links.html.erb to contain only the links you want to show.

To allow only existing users to create new users, you will want to at least place restrictions on the Devise::RegistrationsController controller actions new and create. This is a bit complex, and requires creating a custom Devise registrations controller.

To do that, create a file in your controller folder called registrations_controller.rb, and update your routes.rb file to point devise_for :users to that new controller. To restrict actions to signed in users only consider using the Devise helper "authenticate_user!". All of those suggestions together might look like this:

```
#controllers/registration_controllers.rb

class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]

  def new
    super
  end

  def new
    super
  end

end
```

And your routes

```
#config/routes.rb

devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

Ideally, in the views, Users who are not signed in should not even be given the option to try to create new users, so there should be some additional view logic, such as this:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= link_to "New user", new_user_registration_path %>
<% end %>
```

To clean up your view, you might consider extracting conditional view logic like this into helpers.

With this setup, existing users will be able to create new users through the new_user_registration_path.

For more information, the Devise documentation is pretty useful (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) as well as perusing other StackOverflow answers.

Comment: I add this code to my project, when I run the project and click on `New user`, I get this error: `uninitialized constant CustomDevise`.Do you know the reason?

Comment: Sorry, typo. Try the new routes.rb line in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I click on `new user`, page is redirect_to previous page and don't show `sign_up` page.

Comment: That's probably authenticate_user! doing its job. For more information, watch this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise and try reading the Devise documentation.

Comment: If that's the case, sounds like the controller override is working. Mind accepting and upvoting the answer? That's the bit of cheese for us mice.

Comment: @steel have you or anyone else tried building this out? i have something similar but when reaching the `new_user_registration` page it instead redirects to default page with flash message: `You are already signed in.`

Comment: @xst, what a difference a year made in my perspective. I wouldn't do it like this anymore, with that custom controller. I would just create a userscontroller and create a new user the way normal records are created, rather than trying to go through Devise's registration controller.